Getting error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected
I'm getting this error:
Uncaught runtime errors:

ERROR
Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28072:15)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31574:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33293:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18263:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18307:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18364:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38262:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37510:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37433:9)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37406:11

From what I have read, this happens if hooks are called within a conditional statment, or if I place return statements above hook calls, among other things.
The error is provoked when I click on this button (Which should navigate me to another page):
<Col xs={1} className="myCol"><Button variant="info" value={v.id} onClick={(e) => requestMemberEdit(e.target.value, 'edit')}>Edit</Button></Col>

The function that is called on the button click, is this:
const requestMemberEdit = (id, type) => {
    navigate("/newmember", { state:{type:type, id: id }} );       
}

And in another file, I'm trying to use location to get the state properties that are sent on the button click.
Here is the entire code for the first file, that contains the code I just showed above (This is the code where the error is thrown)
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ShowMembers = () => {    
    const [allMembers, setAllMembers] = useState({});    
    const [arg, setArg] = useState('');         
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getAllMembers = () => {            
            fetch('/getAllMembers')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(res => {            
                setAllMembers(res)
                //console.log(allMembers)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        };
        getAllMembers();
    }, []);                            
    
    const requestMemberEdit = (id, type) => {
        //console.log('xxxxxx ' + id)
        navigate("/newmember", { state:{type:type, id: id }} );       
    }

    const requestMemberDelete = (id) => {
        if(window.confirm("Delete this member?")) {
            fetch("/api/deleteMember", {
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({id: parseInt(id)})
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                res === true ? alert("User deleted")
                    : alert("Something went wrong, pls try again");
            })            
        }
    }        
        
    return (
        <>       
        <div className="memberDiv">
            <Container className="members">                        
            {
                allMembers.length ?                     
                    allMembers.map(v => <Row key={v.id}>                                            
                                            <Col className="myCol">{v.firstname}</Col>
                                            <Col className="myCol">{v.lastname}</Col>
                                            <Col className="myCol">{v.email}</Col>
                                            <Col className="myCol">{v.birthdate}</Col>
                                            <Col xs={1} className="myCol"><Button variant="danger" value={v.id} onClick={(e) => requestMemberDelete(e.target.value)}>Delete</Button></Col>
                                            <Col xs={1} className="myCol"><Button variant="info" value={v.id} onClick={(e) => requestMemberEdit(e.target.value, 'edit')}>Edit</Button></Col>
                                            
                                        </Row>)
                : <h2>No data</h2>
            }
            </Container>
        </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default ShowMembers;

If you notice this code: const [arg, setArg] = useState('');. I don't use it anywhere. I wanted to remove it, and notice that when removed, it gives another error message. This errormessage is:
Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
at updateReducer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28232:15)
at updateState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28600:14)
at Object.useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29397:20)
at useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47840:25)
at AddMember (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1161:84)
at renderPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:289:70)
at Content (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:302:10)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28005:22)
at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31572:24)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33291:20)

Even though it says that it might be a bug in React, I don't think that it is.
And here is the code from the other file, where I want to use the location
import { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddMember = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    const [oldMember, setOldMember] = useState('')
    const location = useLocation();

    console.log(location)

    if(location.type === 'edit') {
        fetch('/api/getMemberByID', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({id: location.id})
        })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(res => {
            setOldMember(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Could not set old member')
        })
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const submitFormData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await fetch('/newmember', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("ffff:"+data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    };

    return (
        <div className="contentDiv">
            <Form onSubmit={submitFormData} name="formdata" id="formdata">
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Fornavn" value={oldMember ? oldMember.firstname : ''} name="firstname" required onChange={handleChange} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Efternavn" value={oldMember ? oldMember.lastname : ''} name="lastname" required onChange={handleChange} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Email" value={oldMember ? oldMember.email : ''} name="email" required onChange={handleChange} />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Birthday</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="Fødselsdag" name="bday" required onChange={handleChange} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Sport</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" name="sport" type="number" onChange={handleChange} >
                                <option>Vælg aktivitet</option>
                                <option value="1">Hobby 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Hobby 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Hobby 3</option>
                            </Form.Select>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>                            
                            <Form.Check type="checkbox" name="active" label="Active" onChange={handleChange} />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Chip</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="chip" placeholder="Add chip" onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Form.Group>

                <Button type="submit"> Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddMember;

In case that it is of any importance, I'm using BrowserRouter
 function App() {  
  return (
    <>
      <Buttons />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Content />}></Route>
          <Route path='/newmember' element={<Content />}></Route>         
          <Route path='/ShowMembers' element={<Content />}></Route>
          <Route path='/ShowAdmins' element={<Content />}></Route>
          <Route path='/NewAdmin' element={<Content />}></Route>
          <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


My <Content /> component that is referenced in the App() function above, was looking like this:
const Content = () => {
    const URL = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    const renderPage = (url) => {
        switch (url) {
            case 'newmember':
                return AddMember()
            case 'NewAdmin':
                return AddAdmin()
            case 'showMemberByMail':
                return ShowMembers()
            case 'ShowMembers':
                return ShowMembers()
            case 'ShowAdmins':
                return ShowAdmins()
            default:
                return PageNotFound()
        }
    }

    return (
        renderPage(URL)
    )
}

Being new to React, I was not thinking about using JSX syntax on Components, so instead, I ended up calling them like regular functions, which lead to weird behaviors, and especially the problem described above, that was the reason for this post.
So my solution to the problem, was rendering the Components with JSX syntax. Here is how it looks now, which solved my headache/problems
const Content = () => {
    const URL = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    const renderPage = (url) => {
        switch (url) {
            case 'newmember':
                return <AddMember />
            case 'NewAdmin':
                return <AddAdmin />
            case 'showMemberByMail':
                return <ShowMembers />
            case 'ShowMembers':
                return <ShowMembers />
            case 'ShowAdmins':
                return <ShowAdmins />
            default:
                return <PageNotFound />
        }
    }

    return (
        renderPage(URL)
    )
}

If I had posted this file along with the others above, people probably would have spotted my issue, but I had no idea that this file/code would be the issue
